# Use Discard variable in Automapper mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to safely convert comma separated string variable into int list with Automapper mapping.

In version 6.2.2 of Automapper, I did it like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<FilterRequest, Filter>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.SomeIds, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.SomeIds) ? src.SomeIds.Split(',').Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _)).Select(int.Parse).ToList() : null));
```

but after upgrading Automapper to version 8.1.1 the `ResolveUsing` method consolidated with `MapFrom` method.
When i trying to replace my mapping with `MapFrom` using:

```
cfg.CreateMap<FilterRequest, Filter>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.SomeIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.SomeIds) ? src.SomeIds.Split(',').Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _)).Select(int.Parse).ToList() : null))
```

I have an error with discard variable in `TryParse`: *An expression tree may not contain a discard*

How can i use discard variable with Automapper mapping?

Comment: Based on the error message, you probably have to do something like `... int.TryParse(x, out var neverUsed)...`

Comment: You don't need null checks. Also you can map from strings, AM will convert to int for you. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this overload:

```
void MapFrom<TResult>(Func<TSource, TDestination, TResult> mappingFunction);

cfg.CreateMap<FilterRequest, Filter>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.SomeIds,
        opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) => src.SomeIds
            .Split(',')
            .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToList()));
```